# Made a recursive function in C++. Now asked to make a "tail-recursion" function

Tags: c++, recursion

Here is a recursive function I came up with in order to fulfill the requirements of duplicating each letter in a string (i.e. "abc" to "aabbcc"):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string repeater(string str){
    if (str == ""){
        return "";
    }
    else{
        return str.substr(0,1) + str.substr(0,1) + repeater(str.substr(1));
    }
}

int main(){
    string test = "llama";
    cout << "repeater(\"" << test << "\") returned: " << repeater(test) << endl;
}
```

Now I'm asked to make a "tail-recursive" function that does the same thing. I'm reading up on it, and my text gives the following example of a "tail-recursive" function:

```
int factorial(int n) {
if (n == 0)
return 1;
else
return n * factorial(n – 1);
}
```

This looks identical to the method I used to create my own. I need to hand in 2 versions of recursive functions. Is mine already a "tail-recursive" function? If so, how would I make a forward recursive function (or, if the opposite is the case, vice-versa)?

http://ideone.com/JrtRsE

Comment: Tail recursion just does a return of the recursive call. In the example code, the returned value is multiplied by n, so it's not tail recursive.

Comment: Is my text wrong, then? Or am I reading this incorrectly? http://postimg.org/image/jqqxd91xv/

Comment: Look at the examples here [tail recursion](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/what-is-tail-recursion) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
string tail_repeater(string left, string right){
    if (right == ""){
       return left;
    }
    return tail_repeater(left + right.substr(0,1) + right.substr(0,1), right.substr(1));
}

string repeater(string str){
   tail_repeater("", str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to have to learn to wrap my head around this. I've read recursion's functionality is almost the same as looping's. I guess thinking that way will help me figure out what's going on as I step through it in the debugger. Cheers~

Comment: I learned about tail recursion when I learned to program in Scheme. If you have the time, I would recommend giving it a try.